# can someone help me to add some condition for different user level

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a beginner for php PDO please help mo on where and how to made condition for the different user level using redirecting in different page base on the different user login . Thank you

this is my code for login

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  require_once("user.php");
  $login = new USER();

  if($login->is_loggedin()!="")
  {
    $login->redirect('database.php');
  }

  if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
  {
   $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
   $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
   $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

  if($login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)) 
  {
    $login->redirect('database.php');
 }
   else
   {
    $error = "Invalid Username/Email !!!";
   }    
 }
?>
```

this is my condition in my login using PDO

```
 <?php

require_once('login_db.php');

class USER
{
private $conn;

public function __construct()
{
    $database = new DatabaseLogin();
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function runQuery($sql)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt;
}

public function register($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name,user_email,user_pass) 
                                                   VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);                                        

        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}

public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function is_loggedin()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public function redirect($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
}

public function doLogout()
{
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: any errors? checking for them via php and exceptions?

Comment: nothing just a condition for redirecting user level

Comment: Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and see if anything comes of it. And make sure the password column length is long enough.

Comment: no error . all I need is a additional condition for different user level

Answer (score -1):

Prepare a set of user roles based on which you can redirect users to particular pages say 
Admin
Manager
Moderator

Decide where to keep the user roles, either you can keep in tbl_user or you can create a table with tbl_user_role to keep track of user id and role.

After login, get the role of user based on where you are keeping the role name. Now using this role name, redirect the user

If you decided to keep user role inside tbl_user, add a column `user_role` 
Now modify function do_login

```
public function doLogin($uname, $umail, $upass)
{
    try
    {
        //If you are keeping user role in tbl_user modify like this
        $stmt    = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass, user_role FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname' => $uname, ':umail' => $umail));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if (password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_role'] = $userRow['user_role'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

If you are using separate table say `tbl_user_role` for keeping user role information, use following version of doLogin function

```
public function doLogin($uname, $umail, $upass)
{
    try
    {
        //If you are keeping user role in tbl_user modify like this
        $stmt    = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname' => $uname, ':umail' => $umail));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $stmt    = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_role FROM tbl_user_role WHERE user_id=:uid ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $userRow['user_id']));
        $userRole = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if (password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_role'] = $userRole['user_role'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Now you have to create a function redirectByRole inside the class User

```
public function redirectByRole()
{
    $role = !empty($_SESSION['user_role']) ? $_SESSION['user_role'] : false;
    switch ($role)
    {
        case 'admin':
            $login->redirect('admin.php');
            break;
        case 'manager':
            $login->redirect('manager.php');
            break;
        default :
            $login->redirect('logout.php');
            break;
    }
}
```

Now modify your code as follows

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once("user.php");
  $login = new USER();

  if($login->is_loggedin()!="")
  {
    $login->redirectByRole();
  }

  if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
  {
   $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
   $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
   $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

   if($login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)) 
   {
       $login->redirectByRole();
   }
   else
   {
       $error = "Invalid Username/Email !!!";
   }    
 }
```

Comment: can you please make a sample code for that . still not familiar for the php code